# Ximenes rolling in grave

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
1. Ginger received a bit of support (6)
4. Accomplished designer of new road east of Mexican city (8)
10. Readmit resort's host (6,1)
11. Friends going around star pilot's luxurious residences (7)
13. Top inspector voided standards agreements (5)
14. Bringers of salvation leave me out, leading to sensations (7)
15. Prefix for new origin of natural gas (4)
18. A muppet is ultimately thrown in the middle of lake (5)
19. No duties to make exceptions (9)
20. Former eco-unit dished out punishment (9)
22. Heading to let it out (5)
23. Dance for Mike (4)
25. Locked in house, a son sees different times of year (7)
28. Confirmed winners hugging reporter Newman (5)
29. Country man to create wrappers for medicine (7)
30. Be on top of almost unconcealed falsehood (7)
31. Sir Walter is originally honouring his ethnicity? (8)
32. Mysterious small island's eastern part moved all the way west (6)

**Down**
1. Mixed, rest remade, having improved sound quality? (10)
2. "Before the last of…"? – Ximenes rolling in grave over clue-framing violations (10)
3. Find new way out in two notes (7)
5. Development of entrances to expensive luxurious house not starting (9)
6. African president and admiral's new lesson broadcast (7)
7. Pursuit for ethnic group (4)
8. Get rid of sculpture having goose egg for head (4)
9. Chances of strange events ending (4)
12. A social lubricant is essential to social encounters (3)
16. Defraud online provocator? Vacuous endeavour for responsible person (10)
17. Evaluation of agreement: "Horrible mess in the middle" (10)
19. Warm soup I served resulted in conflicts (5,4)
21. A thousand missing – the truck destroyed city (7)
22. Bar ambush – oddly, Eazy-E is behind it (7)
24. Composition due to be paid, by the sound of it (3)
25. Porky female gets new shade of white… (4)
26. …after retirement; essentially gives up on work (4)
27. Sundown covers ruin (4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grid:

> [image: img2]

The explanation: (On 26D, I am not sure if I have the correct explanation.)

> ACROSS
>  1 "roger" + s(upport) 
>  4 Leon + road*
>  10 readmit*    ("resorted")
>  11 'pals' containing 'ace'
>  13 ideals - i   (thanks to @Tom)
>  14 sav(i)ours
>  15 neo + n(atural)
>  18 'erie' containing '(throw)n'
>  19 0 + missions
>  20 ex + ecounit*
>  22 letit*
>  23 pro (Latin 'for') + M  (phonetic alphabet)
>  25 a son sees*
>  28 hidden: confirmED WINners
>  29 panama [m -> c(reat)e]
>  30 over(t) + lie
>  31 scott + is + h(onouring)
>  32 s(mall) + crete, with final e shifted to front
>  DOWN
>  1 rest remade*
>  2 (in grave)* + c(lu)e + s
>  3 'out' inside re+re
>  5 exp(ensive) + (m)ansion
>  6 n. + lesson*
>  7 double def'n
>  8 bust -> oust
>  9 odd + (event)s
>  12 hidden: sociAL Encounters
>  16 con + troll + e(ndeavou)r
>  17 'assent' containing mess*
>  19 warm soup i*
>  21 thetruck* - K
>  22 trap + EaZyE
>  24 sounds like "owed"
>  25 'sow' containing 'n'
>  26  hidden backwards:  giveS UP On  
>  27 hidden: sUNDOwn